# Help clarifying entropy concept

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I've been having difficulties clarifying 
the concept of entropy in thermodynamics
for a while , I understand the explanation in Statistical Mechanics 
 but I want to understand it
from a thermodynamical view, I know that we can calculate the wasted 
work because of entropy by the formula
$$
X_\textrm{destroyed} = S_\textrm{gen}\cdot \textrm{temperature} 
$$
but where did this energy loss came from?
And why did it happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's the result of viscous dissipation of mechanical energy to internal (thermal) energy.  The rate of viscous dissipation is proportional to the square of the rate at which the fluid is deforming.  So, for a very gradual deformation, the rate of viscous dissipation is very low.  But, for a rapid irreversible deformation, the rate of viscous dissipation is significant.